# NullPointer Exception when trying to Mock Firebasefirestore in java

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mockito

I used this code in a repository, but now that i want to do unit test. I need to mock this part, but i have null pointer exception. I don't know at all what to do.

```
firebaseFirestore
    .collection("chat")
    .document(roomId)
    .collection("messages")
    .add(chatMessage);
```

I think it is because after mocking all the lines, i don't know what to give as value for each.

Comment: As far as I can see, that is a real object and not a mock object, right?

Comment: That's the point, how to do a mock on this real object, and give a value for each lines, to not get a NPE !?